# How to show Autocomplete for text fields in infopath 2013?

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules

I have one info Path form I want to implement the Autocomplete text box.When user Enter A show all the related value.This form is only open in info path filler how can I achieve this.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Infpath Designer 2013 > open your current template >

- Right click on your Textbox >
- Select TextBox Properties > At Display Tab >
- Check Enble AutoComplete

[image]

Also, check How to Achieve this via Jquery at [Using SPServices with jQueryUI’s Autocomplete Function on InfoPath Forms in SharePoint](http://sympmarc.com/2011/08/24/using-spservices-with-jqueryuis-autocomplete-function-on-infopath-forms-in-sharepoint/)